# Search values in table based on any one of the field

Tags: java, spring-boot, api, hibernate

I have created an API which manages contact for a user. The Contact table contains following fields.

```
ID          NUMBER(10,0)        
EMAIL       VARCHAR2(255 CHAR)
FIRST_NAME  VARCHAR2(255 CHAR)  
LAST_NAME   VARCHAR2(255 CHAR)  
PHONE       VARCHAR2(255 CHAR)
```

I want to search for a contact based on either the FIRST_NAME, LAST_NAME or EMAIL field, what is the correct way to approach this. I am thinking of writing a query using OR operator, also I don't know how to receive the input from user request. Should it be a path variable in a get request? how would I know whether user is trying to search based on what field if I just receive one path variable in request?

Below is my Controller class so far. I have not yet implemented the above scenario.

```
package com.shivam.cms.controller;

import com.shivam.cms.dto.ContactDTO;
import com.shivam.cms.service.ContactService;
import com.shivam.cms.utils.Response;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;

import java.util.List;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/cms")
public class ContactController {

    @Autowired
    ContactService contactService;

    @GetMapping("/contacts")
    public ResponseEntity<?> getContacts(){
        List<ContactDTO> contacts = contactService.findAllContacts();
        if(contacts.size()==0)
            return new ResponseEntity<>(new Response("No contacts are present in system","Success"),HttpStatus.OK);
        return new ResponseEntity<>(contacts,HttpStatus.OK);
    }

    @PostMapping("/add")
    public ResponseEntity<ContactDTO> addContact(@RequestBody ContactDTO contactDto){
        ContactDTO contact = contactService.addContact(contactDto);
        return new ResponseEntity<>(contact, HttpStatus.CREATED);
    }

    @GetMapping("/contacts/{id}")
    public ResponseEntity<?> getContact(@PathVariable Integer id){
        ContactDTO contact=null;
        try {
            contact= contactService.findContact(id);
        }
        catch (Exception e){
            return new ResponseEntity<>(new Response(e.getMessage(),"Failed"),HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
        }
        return new ResponseEntity<>(contact,HttpStatus.OK);
    }

    @DeleteMapping("/delete/{id}")
    public ResponseEntity<?> deleteContact(@PathVariable Integer id){
        ContactDTO contact=null;
        try {
            contact= contactService.deleteContact(id);
        }
        catch (Exception e){
            return new ResponseEntity<>(new Response(e.getMessage(),"Failed"),HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
        }
        return new ResponseEntity<>(contact,HttpStatus.OK);
    }

    @PutMapping("/update/{id}")
    public ResponseEntity<?> updateContact(@PathVariable Integer id, @RequestBody ContactDTO contactDTO){
        ContactDTO contact=null;
        try {
            contact = contactService.updateContact(contactDTO,id);
        }
        catch (Exception e){
            return new ResponseEntity<>(new Response(e.getMessage(),"Failed"),HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
        }
        return new ResponseEntity<>(contact,HttpStatus.OK);
    }
}
```

Comment: For a search operation, the user should specify on which field they want to search. In your case that would mean, you have up to 3 different input fields, which contents you send in 3 different variables to the backend. As for the query, you would have multiple options. Either a custom query, multiple queries that search on different fields and combinations of fields, or you create a `CriteriaQuery`. Also, the query shouldn't be using OR operator, as multiple input variables mean that you want to have a more refined filtering

Comment: If you are using JPA, you can create a custom query using the conventions listed in the documentation of JPA. Also, to search by fields, you can create a rest endpoint, you can take the field and value of the field in the Params and use repository accordingly in service. Check- https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repository-query-keywords:~:text=Repository%20query%20keywords-,Supported%20query%20method%20subject%20keywords,-The%20following%20table